# Object.Array.map is undefined ReactJS component MERN Stack

Tags: reactjs, npm, mern

my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './viewAcc.css'
import HttpService from '../../services/http-service'

const http = new HttpService()

function ViewAcc({match}){

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAcc()
    }, [])

    const [acc, setAcc] = useState({})

    const getAcc = async()=>{
        const data = await http.getAcc(match.params.id)
        setAcc(data[0])
    }

    return(
        <div style={{display: "block"}} className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-8" style={{alignItems:"center", marginBottom:"40px"}}>
                    <h3><b>Name: {"\u00a0\u00a0"}</b> {acc.name}</h3>
                    <div style={{display:"flex", alignItems:"center"}}>
                        <h3><b>Phone Nos: </b></h3>
                        {acc.ph_nos.map(i => 
                            <p key={i}>{i}</p>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm">
                    <input></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ViewAcc
```

While I was writing this code and npm was auto refreshing, both the name and phone numbers were displayed (this means that the data is being fetched) but when I went back to the main page and clicked on my dynamic router link,
`TypeError: acc.ph_nos is undefined` Error is displayed.

When I remove the acc.ph_nos.map part, the name is displayed with no errors. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `ph_nos` property an empty array first:

```
const [acc, setAcc] = useState({ph_nos: []})
```

Or, even better, separate out the phone numbers into a separate state variable:

```
const [phoneNumbers, setPhoneNumbers] = useState([]);
// ...
const getAcc = () => {
  http.getAcc(match.params.id).then(data => setPhoneNumbers(data[0].ph_nos));
};
```

and then reference the `phoneNumbers` array instead of `ph_nos` when rendering.

You can also simplify

```
useEffect(()=>{
    getAcc()
}, [])
```

to

```
useEffect(getAcc);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works but can you please exaplain why my method didn't work? Just trying to learn, I'm a beginner.